# How to get the value of an option_name and display on front-end?

Tags: php, wordpress

Creating a basic admin setting page for user to input his social media username, which I then need to make appear on the front-end.
[the admin dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZDEM.png)

functions.php:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'architectura_custom_settings' );
function custom_settings() {
    register_setting( 'architectura-settings-group', 'facebook_handler');
    add_settings_field( 'sidebar-facebook', 'Facebook handler', 'sidebar_facebook', 'admin', 'sidebar-options');
}

function sidebar_facebook() {
    $facebook = esc_attr( get_option( 'facebook_handler' ) );
    echo '<input type="text" name="facebook_handler" value="'.$facebook.'" placeholder="Facebook handler" />';
}
```

The code for the front-end:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/<?php //Facebook field value from back-end here ?>"></a>
```

How can I get what the user types into the Facebook field and output it in the above href?

Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php $options_value = get_option( 'your_registered_option' );
echo $options_value['sample_select_options']; ?>
```

Replace `your_registered_option` with the name you gave in functions php for `register_setting();`.

Comment: <?php $option = get_option( 'your_option' ); echo $option['sample_select_options']; ?>

Comment: This worked, after II took out the `['sample_select_options']`, so thank you:
`<?php $option = get_option( 'facebook_handler' ); echo $option; ?>`